# Why doesn't zsh like a file glob like *17*?

Tags: zsh, wildcards, scp

I am a relatively new zsh user, and love it 99% of the time.  When I try to copy a bunch of files, eg:

```
[I] ➜ ls *17*
core.txt.17   info.17       vmcore.17.zst
```

but when I `scp *17* xxx:xxx/xxx`, I get:

```
[I] ➜ scp *17* freefall.freebsd.org:
*17*: No such file or directory

ler in /var/crash  at borg
[I] ➜
```

Why?

If I run `type scp`, I get:

```
scp is an alias for noglob scp
scp is /usr/bin/scp
```

Comment: What's the `ler in /var/crash  at borg` at the end of the `scp` output about? Is `scp` really `scp` or is it an alias or shell function?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I think that's the first line of their prompt.

Comment: that is the first line of my prompt.  scp is not an alias that I've added (it might be something for the completer but I'm sure (using prezsto).

Comment: what happens if you execute /usr/bin/scp directly?

Comment: @sendmoreinfo that works.  I'm still curious what the hades is going on when it's found on the PATH.

Comment: might be something unexpected.  check what scp actually finds - `type scp` should show if it's an alias, a function, or a binary

Comment: [I] ➜ type scp
scp is an alias for noglob scp
scp is /usr/bin/scp

~
[I] ➜
that's interesting....  Now to find where it's set :)

Answer (score 4):

As you've discovered, zsh has a way to disable wildcard expansion on certain commands. If you put [`noglob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-noglob) before a command, zsh doesn't do wildcard expansion on the words of the command. Since typing `noglob` is often as much effort as quoting wildcard characters in arguments, the most common use is to automatically cause certain commands to be “noglobbed” by making the command name an alias to the same command name with the `noglob` prefix. For example, after

```
alias scp='noglob scp'
```

you won't get any wildcard expansion on the `scp` command line, but other than that the `scp` command will run normally.

You can bypass the alias with

```
\scp *17* freefall.freebsd.org:
```

or

```
=scp *17* freefall.freebsd.org:
```

`\scp` bypasses the alias and looks for a function, builtin or external command by that name. `=scp` only looks for an external command.

Preventing wildcard expansion for arguments of `scp` lets you write `scp remote:*17*` without quotes, but it comes with the major downside of not letting you write `scp *17* remote:`. It's possible to take this further and cause arguments of `scp` to have wildcards expanded only if they don't look like remote file names. Here's a function that analyzes the arguments of `scp` and only expands wildcards in arguments that don't look like options or remote file names.

```
function glob_non_remote {
  local a x
  a=($1); shift
  for x; do
    # Do wildcard expansion manually, but only for arguments that don't look
    # like options or remote file names.
    case $x in
      (*:*|-*|) a+=("$x");;
      *) a+=($~x);;
    esac
  done
  "${(@)a}"
}
alias scp='noglob glob_non_remote scp'
```